# Return the date where minimum threshold was reached

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I tried to create a Dax measure to give me the date where minimum threshold was reached based on sum of accepted records and grouped by userid, campaignid and country. I want to get the exact date where sum of acceptedrecords >= the minimumthreshold, for each userid, campaignid and country.

```
Datesmet =
 var MinimumThresholdDate =
CALCULATE (
    min(
Table[date]) , filter( ALLEXCEPT(table,table[userid],table[campaignid],table[Country]),
     Table[Acceptedrecords] >= table[minimumthreshold]
            && NOT(ISBLANK(table[dailyincreincentive])))
)
return
if (
 min(table[date_of_review]) <= MinimumThresholdDate || max(table[date_of_review])<MinimumThresholdDate, blank(), min(table[date_of_review]))
```

This just gives me the dates where sum of accepted records >= minimumthreshold, at row level for userid, campaignid, country, date etc, when I put it into a table with these fields.

You can find the sample file [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QxgQyfjQYECI2vWhAGH-IzQjSTvY7zbY)

Comment: You need to supply some sample data and expected output for people to help. Do you have a sample .pbix?

Comment: Have added the sample file @DavideBacci! Thanks for asking!

Comment: Hi no it wasn't, I'm away from my PC but I'll try to get back on this

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
Measure = 
VAR t = ADDCOLUMNS(
    ALL('Table'),
    "@x", 
    VAR d = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[date_of_review])
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(SUM( 'Table'[Acceptedrecords]), 'Table'[date_of_review] <= d, REMOVEFILTERS())
)

RETURN CALCULATE( MAXX(t,  'Table'[date_of_review]), FILTER(t, [@x] >= 'Table'[minimum_threshold]))
```